# Using Kotlin streams and filter throws a cannot cast to my custom type exception

Tags: kotlin

I am exploring the equivalent of C# Linq but in Kotlin, so I came across streams:

```
val c = Manager.customers.entries.stream()
                        .filter { x -> x.value.name == "Jaime Garcia" }
```

// after this c is a ReferencePipeline type... apparently. Consider also that Manager.customers is of type  HashMap().

And then when I use it:
    `val id = (c as Customer)?.id`

... it throws an error :

> java.lang.ClassCastException : java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2
>   cannot be cast to com.example.mypackage.Customer

Maybe I should map c otherwise before using, I tried with something like `.collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a.getValue()))` appended after the filter but syntactically it doesn't even work

Comment: Stream.filter() returns a Stream: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-. Not a Customer. It's unclear what you want to achieve. If you want the first element matching the predicate, then use `.findFirst()`, which will return an `Optional<Map.Entry<Something, SomethingElse>>`. Read the javadoc: it helps a lot. And ask you IDE to specify the type of your variables. You shouldn't have to cast anything.

Answer (score 4):

You should not be using Java's stream API in Kotlin *. Instead you should be using what the Kotlin standard library offers to you to work with collections.

If your customers map looks like this:

```
val customers = mapOf(1 to Customer("Foo"), 2 to Customer("Bar"))
```

you can retrieve a list of matching Customers like this:

```
val c = customers.values.filter { x -> x.name == "Foo" }
```

Note that `c` will be a List.

If you want a single element right away, use `firstOrNull` (for example):

```
val foo = customers.values.firstOrNull { x -> x.name == "Foo" }

val id = c?.id // id will be null or a Customer
```

---

<sub>At least as long as you can avoid it. I just found out that the Kotlin standard library offers [utility functions to work with Java 8 streams](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.streams/index.html), so it seams that it is not discouraged.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use proper Kotlin syntax, you can also use [find](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/find.html):

```
Manager.customers.values
    .find { it.name == "Jaime Garcia" }
    ?.id
```

Comment: `let` is redundant here. `Manager.customers.values.find { it.name == "Jaime Garcia" }?.id` :)